# Launch one addin from another addin in excel

Tags: excel, office-js

We have developed a couple of excel addins with office-js and are finding that it would be really handy to be able to launch one addin from another addin and even possibly pass some data between the 2.  Is the launching at least possible?

Comment: This would be security issue when an add-in will be able to manipulate others. For this obvious reason this is not possible. Usually I advise to use [https://officespdev.uservoice.com/](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) to request unimplemented feature, but in your case Office team will never allow it anyway.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov You are correct. There is no API in Office.js at this time that would enable an add-in to launch a different add-in. Please make your comment into an answer.

Comment: I feel like that is a poor answer.  This is a common ability in other platforms take Android for example.  One application can submit a request using intents and another application can register as being able to handle that request.  This doesn't need to be a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you own both add-ins**, you could navigate to one or the other via the URL's you placed in your manifest file. This could allow you to launch another add-in, **however it would be inside the same task pane.**

You could also pass data between both apps via url query parameters.

I've done this before when I made an add-in that was a landing page for other add-ins. When you clicked on a button for another tool, it would navigate to another add-in (which was a separate project) and pass the previous tool as a parameter in the URL so you could navigate back to where you came from.

It'd also be possible to share data on a private sheet inside Excel.

Answer (score -1):

This would be security issue when an add-in will be able to manipulate others. For this obvious reason this is **not possible**.

Usually I advise to use https://officespdev.uservoice.com/ to request unimplemented feature, but based on your description, Office team most likely won't allow it anyway.